# share type definitions in source files

Tags: c, resource-files

I'm just new to this separating source files.
.
Is it possible to share the my type defined to any other source files?
.
.
.

This is my definitions in myTypeDef.h

```
typedef struct
{
    int x, y, w, h;
    short life;
}Man;
```

What if I create a new .h (named draw.h) file that will draw the image like this:

```
#include "myTypeDef.h"


void rendererFunction(Man *man);
```

Then I create a .c (named draw.c) file that will implement what's in draw.h like this:

```
#include "draw.h"

void rendererFunction(Man *man)
{
    draw(man->x, man->y, man->w, man->y);
}
```

Then what if I also created a update.h (and update.c for implementation) file that will update his position? Do I really have to connect the draw.h to update.h just to get my type defined object? Or is there any other way of sharing type defined object without repeating the definition when I include the .h's in my main??

I hope someone can help me. Thanks

Comment: ok sir. I'll try to edit and make this as short as possible. Thanks for that advice.

Comment: @KenWhite. Is this edit alright sir? I hope you can help me. I'm just confused with this new concept that I learned. The separation of codes.

Comment: Much better. Thanks. :-)

Comment: @KenWhite. No sir, Thanks to you. =)

Comment: Have you tried to use [`include guard`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) to prevent double inclusion?

Answer (score 1):

A common idiom in c header files are inclusion guards. These use the preprocessor to prevent things like multiple definitions. They look something like :

```
#ifndef MYMODULE_MYFILENAME_H
#define MYMODULE_MYFILENAME_H
.... Your definitions.... 
#endif
```

This allows you to always include the header containing what a given file is using, even if some other file *happens* to also include the header you need. Indeed this is good practice so that if later you refactor a header file to no longer include the file you need, some seemingly unrelated code doesn't start failing to compile.

Answer (score 0):

In your `update.h`, just `include "myTypeDef.h"`. Like what you do with `draw.h` and `draw.c`;

Or in your `draw.h` and `update.h`, just use sentence `struct Man;` to declare the struct. And in your `draw.c` and `update.c` use `include "MyTypeDef.h"`.

Comment: No sir. I think I can't do that because when I include the draw.h and update.h in my main, there will be a repetition of definition of my "Man".. hence, compiler error.